# Launchd will not execute plist. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: launchd

I am trying to create a plist for a unix executable. The executable works perfectly well when I run it in Terminal. However I simply cannot get it to run from launchd. Here are the steps I took:

```
sudo touch /Library/LaunchDaemons/Parity.plist

sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/Parity.plist
```

Then I input the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
      <key>Label</key>
        <string>Parity</string>
      <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>/usr/local/Cellar/parity/1.5.12/bin/parity</string>
          <string>start</string>
        </array>
      <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
      <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
   </dict>
</plist>
```

If I run:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/parity.plist
```

I get the response:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/Parity.plist: service already loaded
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: you have to unload it first:  `sudo launchctl unload...` then load it again `sudo launchctl load...`

Comment: @Allan Thanks for your reply. I followed your advice, but it unfortunately has not made any difference. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Try removing it `sudo launchctl remove...` to remove it.  Then reload.

Comment: @Allan Unfortunately that didn't work either. However I have found that when I run `launchctl list` I get `- 1 Parity`. Everything else has a 0 next to it.

Comment: That means the program or script exited with an error so the plist is loading, it's just Parity is erroring out.  What does the log for Parity say?

Comment: @Allan You're right about that. I got to the bottom of it. I wrote a bad .plist, and had to delete `<string>start</string>`. It works perfectly now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Post your solution as an answer so you can "accept it" and I can vote you up for some reputation points.

Comment: @Allan I updated my post with the solution. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @klanomath My apologies. I am new here. I have now added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the cause of the error was a poorly written plist - `<string>start</string>` was instructing the exec file to run a `start` command when initiating the daemon, which was causing it to crash. I erased that line from the plist and now it behaves as I had intended.